# Symfony 5 : Problem userProvider does not contain an identifier from an extended class

Tags: symfony4, symfony-security, symfony5

I have class "etudiant" extends from user.
the problem is when i try to login/logout with an "etudiant" account, i have this message : You cannot refresh a user from the EntityUserProvider that does not contain an identifier. The user object has to be serialized with its own identifier mapped by Doctrine.

User Entity :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"user" = "User" , "etudiant" = "Etudiant"})
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
     */
    private $roles = [];

    /**
     * @var string The hashed password
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $prenom;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUsername(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    public function setRoles(array $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        // not needed when using the "bcrypt" algorithm in security.yaml
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
        // $this->plainPassword = null;
    }

    public function getNom(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    public function setNom(string $nom): self
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPrenom(): ?string
    {
        return $this->prenom;
    }

    public function setPrenom(string $prenom): self
    {
        $this->prenom = $prenom;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Etudiant Entity

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\AttributeOverride;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\EtudiantRepository")
 *  @ORM\AttributeOverrides({
 *      @AttributeOverride(name="id",
 *          column=@Column(
 *              name     = "id",
 *              type     = "integer",
 *              length   = 140
 *          )
 *      )
 * })
 */
class Etudiant extends User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     */
    private $date_naissance;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $sexe;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $ville;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Encadrant", inversedBy="etudiants")
     */
    private $encadrant;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Formation", inversedBy="etudiants")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $formation;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Stage", mappedBy="etudiant")
     */
    private $stages;

    protected $discr = 'etudiant';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->stages = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }


    public function getDateNaissance(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->date_naissance;
    }

    public function setDateNaissance(\DateTimeInterface $date_naissance): self
    {
        $this->date_naissance = $date_naissance;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSexe(): ?int
    {
        return $this->sexe;
    }

    public function setSexe(int $sexe): self
    {
        $this->sexe = $sexe;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getVille(): ?string
    {
        return $this->ville;
    }

    public function setVille(string $ville): self
    {
        $this->ville = $ville;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEncadrant(): ?Encadrant
    {
        return $this->encadrant;
    }

    public function setEncadrant(?Encadrant $encadrant): self
    {
        $this->encadrant = $encadrant;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFormation(): ?Formation
    {
        return $this->formation;
    }

    public function setFormation(?Formation $formation): self
    {
        $this->formation = $formation;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Stage[]
     */
    public function getStages(): Collection
    {
        return $this->stages;
    }

    public function addStage(Stage $stage): self
    {
        if (!$this->stages->contains($stage)) {
            $this->stages[] = $stage;
            $stage->addEtudiant($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeStage(Stage $stage): self
    {
        if ($this->stages->contains($stage)) {
            $this->stages->removeElement($stage);
            $stage->removeEtudiant($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Security.yaml

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto

    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: lazy
            provider: app_user_provider
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: app_logout
                # where to redirect after logout
                # target: app_any_route
            access_denied_handler: App\Security\AccessDeniedHandler
            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
    access_control:
#        - { path: '^/admin', roles: [ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN, ROLE_ADMIN]}
        - { path: '^/admin', roles: ROLE_ADMIN}
        - { path: ^/front, roles: ROLE_ETUDIANT }
```

Error : 
[image] 
can't found any solution. How can I resolve this problem. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to remove the override in Entity Etudiant

```
   *  @ORM\AttributeOverrides({
 *      @AttributeOverride(name="id",
 *          column=@Column(
 *              name     = "id",
 *              type     = "integer",
 *              length   = 140
 *          )
 *      )
 * })
```

and remove the methode getId() from Entity Etudiant

Comment: Thanks to answering your own problem, but I think you did something else, as I have the same problem but no overriding :/

Answer (score 0):

You should have a protected Id, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29829198)

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem on Symfony 6, to fix it I found [this solution](https://grafikart.fr/forum/32317) (which is compatible with flash messages) :

```php
           $this->container->get('security.token_storage')->setToken(null);

            $em->remove($user);
            $em->flush();

            $this->addFlash('success','Your account has been deleted');
            return $this->redirectToRoute('login');
```